# Can HFP (Hands Free Profile) provide stereo audio playback in anyway for Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, bluetooth

I have Samsung Galaxy Buds2 Pro. Audio playback is stereo like for Spotify music but for Zoom calls the microphone is needed and the moment mic is activated Windows switches to HFP mode and the audio playback becomes mono.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/451316

Is there any way or workaround when we can still get stereo audio playback while the mic is on (therefore HFP on)?

Comment: As far as I remember HFP can provide only mono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The codecs used for hands free or headset protocols are mono-only.

[Hands-Free_Profile](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Hands-Free_Profile_(HFP))

> It commonly uses Synchronous Connection Oriented link (SCO) to carry a **monaural audio channel** with continuously variable slope delta modulation or pulse-code modulation, and with logarithmic a-law or μ-law quantization. **Version 1.6 adds optional support for wide band speech with the mSBC codec, a 16 kHz monaural configuration of the SBC codec** mandated by the A2DP profile. Version 1.7 adds indicator support to report such things as headset battery level.

So later versions might support *better* audio, but not stereo.

Also [Headset Profile](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Headset_Profile_(HSP))

> This is the most commonly used profile, providing support for the popular Bluetooth headsets to be used with mobile phones and gaming consoles. It relies on **SCO audio** encoded in 64 kbit/s CVSD or PCM and a subset of AT commands from GSM 07.07 for minimal controls including the ability to ring, answer a call, hang up and adjust the volume.

So the headset profile uses the same audio codec as the hands free profile.

The only way to get stereo audio is to use a separate device for the microphone which will allow the earbuds to be used exclusively for A2DP stereo audio.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. So if I buy a Bluetooth microphone, do I still encounter this issue? It seems only way to use Bluetooth microphone is activating HFP, which will kill stereo of galaxy buds again if they are used simultaneously . Is buying a "wired microphone" only option to have stereo playback sound for Bluetooth earbuds while mic is on?

Comment: It depends whether your computer bluetooth receiver can do multiple devices simultaneously. If it can then *in theory* they should be distinct and separate audio streams and using the microphone on one should not disable stereo audio on the other. Personally I prefer a separate wired microphone and using the high quality audio on the headset.

Comment: I see thanks again, so it comes to me all these Bluetooth earbuds with mics are hype, right? why do they not fix this mic and stereo sound issue? or why do not not pack mic and earphone as 2 separate Bluetooth device packed into 1 to fix it? Do you have any insights for that?

Comment: I've never been "hyped" for bluetooth, it's just a least-worst option until something better comes along. They do pack them in as two devices in one, it's just that in 99.9% of these buds that they can only do one thing at a time. They have an electronic path for mic+mono and another path for stereo audio. In order to use both at the same time they would need to somehow mix the outputs from those two paths and that adds a lot more complexity and assumes that the connected device can also support two devices at the same time which is not going to be common due to bandwidth problems.

Comment: There are some murmurings of using ultra-low power wifi instead of bluetooth in one of the next generations of wireless headphones and frankly I can't wait. Lossless audio and decent quality microphones need far more bandwidth than bluetooth can provide. When bluetooth finally dies I will be happy so see it go.

Comment: Honestly the only time I trust bluetooth for anything is playing music from a phone. Beyond that the quality and experience is entirely questionable. I'd never connect a pair of bluetooth headphones or earbuds to a computer because even when you do get good quality audio from them the latency is absolutely awful for anything other than listening to music. Bluetooth is awful for gaming for mice, keyboards and for audio due to latency and the fact you can click your mouse, wait 50ms for it to do something, then wait another 200ms for audio to come back. It just makes for an awful experience.

Comment: Thanks again. Much learned. During search, I found this new lightspeed technology of logitect, https://www.amazon.com/Logitech-Wireless-Headset-Black-Tico/dp/B081415GCS/ but the reviews say the connection is not reliable.

Comment: The Logitech is not Bluetooth.